# Confusion over W3C POWDER standard (PICS alternative)

Tags: meta-tags, adult-content

Now that [PICS](http://www.w3.org/PICS/) is dead, I still need an easy way to tell users that my website is for mature audiences only. I intend to use PICS tags, but [POWDER](http://www.w3.org/2007/powder/) is said to be the new standard. Is it really used? And how do I set it up? Are there simple example XML files which I can copy for my own use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, it appears that these standards are **both** somewhat dead. And I see why, I have no desire to help the content filter authors 'classify' my site. I merely want to tag not appropriate for minors so to avoid the attack of parent groups.

This tag seems to be what the majority of sites use:

```
<meta name="RATING" content="RTA-5042-1996-1400-1577-RTA" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer above, that tag is not an example but a specific value proposed by [Restricted to Adults (RTA)](http://www.rtalabel.org/index.php?content=howto#individual) for tagging adult pages. Which is *much* simpler than both PICS and POWDER.